# How to solve this using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have managed to solve this ODE
$$y''+4y=\cos(2x)$$
using comparison of coefficient, and I get:
$$y(x) = C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{4}x\sin(2x)$$

Using parameters variation I get:
$$y(x) = C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{4}\cos(2x)\cos(4x)+\frac{1}{2}x\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{8}\sin(4x)\sin(2x)$$

However, trying to get my first solution from the second, I get stuck. I tried using trigonometric identities and the fact that $y_h$ can "swallow" solutions of the form $A\cos(2x)$ and $B\sin(2x)$ where $A,B$ are constants.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: The coefficients of the third and fifth terms must match. Check your calculations again.

Comment: Checked it using Cramer's rule and got both coefficients of sin4xsin2x and cos4xcos2x as 1/16. Thanks!

Comment: To match you would need to get the identity $$\cos(2x)=\cos(4x-2x)=\cos(4x)\cos(2x)+\sin(4x)\sin(2x).$$

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to determine a particular solution you can consider to make a complex immersion:

$$
\cases{
y''+4y = \cos(2x)\\
i(u''+4u) = i \sin(2x)
}\Rightarrow z''+4z = e^{2ix}
$$

then as $z_h =c_0 e^{2ix} + c_1 e^{-2ix}$ we choose as particular solution $z_p=c_2x e^{2ix}$ so

$$
i(i+4c_2)e^{2ix}=0\Rightarrow c_2 = -\frac i4
$$

and then

$$
z_p = -\frac i4 x\left(\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)\right) = \frac x4\sin(2x)-i\frac x4\cos(2x) = y_p + i u_p
$$

then $y_p = \frac x4\sin(2x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the para
Find the general solution
$$
y''+4y=0
$$
The characteristic equation is:
$$
r^{2}+4=0
$$
So,
$$
y_{h}(x)=\mathrm{C_{1}}\cos(2x)+\mathrm{C}_{2}\sin(2x)
$$
Since the right side of the non-homogeneous equation is $\cos(2x)$, and $\cos(2x)$ is already a part of the homogeneous solution, we need to use a parameter variable.
$$
y_{p}(x)=x(A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x))
$$
Put it into the equation:
$$
2 (2 B \cos (2 x)-2 A \sin (2 x))+x (-4 A \cos (2 x)-4 B \sin (2 x))+4x(A\cos(2x)+B \sin(2x))=\cos(2x)
$$

$$
A=0,\quad B=\frac{1}{4}
$$
So,
$$
y(x)=\mathrm{C_{1}}\cos(2x)+\mathrm{C_{2}}\sin(2x)+\frac{x}{4}\sin(2x)
$$

Comment: This was the first, successful method mentioned in the question, "comparison of coefficients", "undetermined parameters" or "intelligent guessing". The question itself in the second part was about the execution of the method of variation of coefficients/parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cramer's rule i got:
$$y(x) = C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{16}\cos(2x)\cos(4x)+\frac{1}{4}x\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{16}\sin(4x)\sin(2x)$$

Which then gives:
$$y(x) = C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{4}x\sin(2x)$$

Thanks!